# Galera cluster - start a node outside the cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, mariadb, galera

I have an application running on two servers. There is a mariadb running on each one of them and a galera cluster that takes care of the replication.

When upgrading the app I need to stop the replication, so I wanted some guidelines on how I can start up the db outside the cluster for one of the servers and then what's the best way to reconnect it.

All ideas are appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the node from the cluster by setting 'wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://' in the config file of the node.Then restart the server,this time the node will be running outside the cluster,hence,no replication.Similarly,to reconnect change the wsrep_cluster_address to whatever it was earlier and restart the node.
Hope it helps.